# Не могу сделать непрерывное считывание нажатий InputProcessor-a Java LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

У меня проблема, я не понимаю как мне в классе реализованном от интерфейса InputProcessor считывать непрерывно нажатие по экрану, есть ли в LibGDX какие-нибудь альтернативы чтобы считывать несколько касаний одновременно и непрерывно. Пробовал уже с помощью Gdx.input.isTouched(), но у меня не получилось сделать чтобы работал мультитач

Сам метод touchDown из InputProcessor
[image: touchDown]

Comment: не понял вопрос, мультитач будет отрабатывать правильно, можно несколько пальцев опустить и будет несколько вызовов touchDown без touchUp, насколько я помню

Comment: @Maxgmer, да, я уже все решил, спасибо)